# Publishing Android Wear + Mobile App on Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, google-play-services, wearables

I have a comprehension question. I have an Android project in which there are two modules. One is a mobile application and the other is a wearable application. Both apps communicate with each other when they are running. Now I want to upload both apps to the Google Playstore, the mobile app can run alone the wearable app cannot. Since both have the same package name I can't publish them separately. How to proceed in such a case? I have the same problem with Firebase App Distribution.

Comment: No one any idea?